# Einstein Chatbot - Add "Send" button

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I am looking to add "Send" button in the Einstein Chatbot which users will click to send message. Right now, there is no button so when user enter something he/she need to press enter. If we need to add a button, how do we achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Send button not available on chat window at moment.  Kindly review [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhRIUAZ/send-button-not-available-in-salesforce-lightening-agent-chat-window) and vote for this feature.

Thanks